How to switch BigQuery connections dynamically for the same dashboard in Superset (Embedded)?
I am trying to embed a Superset dashboard that always displays the same dataset structure (same table names, dataset names), but with different BigQuery connections depending on the client. Each client has its own BigQuery project, and I need the ability to switch between these connections dynamically based on the client using the embedded dashboard.
Problem
I have a dashboard in Superset that is linked to charts, and those charts are linked to datasets with fixed BigQuery connections. The table names and dataset names are the same across all clients, but the BigQuery connections (i.e., the project, credentials, and datasets) differ.
I am embbeding the dashboard in my html file:
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@superset-ui/embedded-sdk"></script>
<script>
  const guestToken = "{{ superset_guest_token }}";  // guest token desde Django
  const dashboardId = "{{ dashboard_id }}";
  const dashboardUrl = "{{ dashboard_url }}";

  supersetEmbeddedSdk.embedDashboard({
    id: dashboardId,  // El ID de tu dashboard
    supersetDomain: dashboardUrl,
    mountPoint: document.getElementById('dashboard-container'),
    fetchGuestToken: () => guestToken,
    dashboardUiConfig: {
      hideTitle: true,
      hideTab: true
    }
  });
  // Solución para ajustar el tamaño del iframe embebido al 100% de ancho y altura
  document.getElementById("dashboard-container").children[0].width = "100%";
  document.getElementById("dashboard-container").children[0].height = "100%";
</script>

When embedding the dashboard, I need to:

Dynamically change the BigQuery connection (credentials and project) depending on the client who is accessing the embedded dashboard.
Ensure the dataset and table names remain the same across all clients.

For example:

Client A: BigQuery project client-a-project, table dataset_a.table_x
Client B: BigQuery project client-b-project, table dataset_a.table_x

The dashboard's structure and SQL queries should remain the same, but the BigQuery connection needs to change based on the client.
Approach Tried

BigQuery SQLAlchemy Connection: I have successfully connected to BigQuery using SQLAlchemy in Superset with the following configuration:


SQLAlchemy URI:

bigquery://<project_id>


Extras field to provide the service account JSON:

{
  "credentials_info": {
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "client-a-project",
    "private_key_id": "YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY_ID",
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nYOUR_PRIVATE_KEY\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    "client_email": "your-service-account@client-a-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "client_id": "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/your-service-account@client-a-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  }
}


Dynamic Dataset Switching with Templates: I attempted to use Jinja templates like {{ current_username() }} or {{ current_user_id() }} in SQL queries to dynamically filter the data, but this doesn't solve the issue of switching BigQuery connections. The dataset/table names are fixed, so it doesn't change the connection.

DB_CONNECTION_MUTATOR (in superset_config.py): I read about the possibility of using DB_CONNECTION_MUTATOR to dynamically switch the connection based on the user or client, but I'm unsure how to apply this in my embedded scenario where I need to pass the correct connection for each client.


Example of a possible DB_CONNECTION_MUTATOR implementation:
def DB_CONNECTION_MUTATOR(uri, params, username, security_manager, source):
    user = security_manager.find_user(username=username)
    if uri.database == "default_bq" and user:
        if user.email.endswith("@clienta.com"):
            uri.host = "bigquery://client-a-project"
            params["credentials_info"] = { ... }  # Credentials for Client A
        elif user.email.endswith("@clientb.com"):
            uri.host = "bigquery://client-b-project"
            params["credentials_info"] = { ... }  # Credentials for Client B
    return uri, params

My Questions

How can I dynamically switch BigQuery connections in Superset for the same dashboard? The connection should change based on the client accessing the embedded dashboard, but the dataset and table names will stay the same.

Can DB_CONNECTION_MUTATOR work in this scenario, and if so, how would I configure it properly? If I need to pass different service account credentials for each client, what should I add to the mutator or elsewhere?

Is there any other way to handle multiple BigQuery connections for the same dataset structure using the embedded Superset SDK? Ideally, I want to configure this dynamically via the backend or during the embedding process.


Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
